# Voltage divider as voltage sense

Tags: pcb, voltage-divider

I used a voltage divider circuit for measuring the battery voltage.  The problem I am facing is that every board needed to be calibrated as the value of resistors vary though I used resistors with 1% tolerance.

Is there any way to self-calibrate the voltage divider?

[image]

Comment: What's the input impedance of `Vsense` node?

Comment: How accurate is your ADC voltage reference?

Comment: Maybe you could do without calibration if you use 0.1% resistors. That is, if you can get them and if the improved accuracy is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Calibration needs something that can store the result. So, no? The simplest you can do for self-calibration will always involve a microcontroller following a calibration routine.

Comment: thank you for the response. i got your point, can you give any example for the calibration routine

Comment: Well, no, because that depends on your method to give a reference input. I mean, that's what calibration is.